# ObjectMapper sets few fields null, but works fine when fields annotated with @JsonProperty

Tags: spring-boot, json-deserialization, objectmapper

When `objectMapper.readValue(<response-entity>.getBody(), RandomEntity.class)` is executed, few fields of `RandomEntity` are missed even tough it is present in the JSON string, saved as null while deserialization.

Has anyone faced similar issue? Annotating fields with `@JsonProperty("attr-name")` seems to solve as a workaround. But this class is used internally only and with 50 attributes, annotation on all makes code look pretty bad.

```
    class WebServiceResponse {
     String id;
     InnerDataObject data;
      <few-more>
     }
```

---

```
     class InnerDataObject {
       String id;
       InnerObject someObject;
     }
```

---

```
     class InnerObject {
      String field1;
      String field2;    //value is null even tough JSON string has correct value
      String field50;
     }
```

---

```
     ObjectMapper mapper = new
     WebServiceResponse result = mapper.readValue(httpResponseEntityObject.getBody() ,                   WebServiceResponse.class);
```

---

Few inner fields have value null even tough it is there in the body.  (The classer are not inner classes)

Annotating `@JsonProperty("field2")` seems to solve the issue but adding this to 50 fields, doesn't it hamper code readability?

*Why does this happen and what's the most optimum fix to this?*

Comment: Hi @Ashwani ! I tried locally with a PoC project and it worked without the issue in your question. May I ask you to provide a sample JSON String and Spring Boot, Jackson version you are using? Also, have you tried the deserialization in an isolated environment (i.e. without Spring)?